# How to clip Drawer underneath AppNar in Material UI without using deprecated makeStyles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer, appbar

I am currently using a latest React v18 with Material UI. makeStyles is now deprecated for this version of React in Material UI.

May I know how I can clip Drawer under the AppBar? There are many solutions, but all of which require makeStyles and it clashes with my React version.

Please see code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-neco-9sum0d?file=/src/App.js).

I want it to look like this, instead of the overlapping thing it's doing now:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Not sure if it might achieve the desired result, but as a possible approach to completely clip `Drawer` under `AppBar`, perhaps try follow these steps in addition to adding `zIndex`.

Forked demo with modifications: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clip-drawer-app-bar-5pck74?file=/src/App.js)

First import and use `CssBaseline` component as it applies the recommended CSS resets by MUI (this will make `AppBar` fill the top area as intended by MUI):

[More about `CssBaseline`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/#main-content)

```
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
  ...
```

Secondly, further style `Drawer` with `sx` so that it leave some space to be clipped by `AppBar`:

```
<Drawer
  anchor="left"
  open={anchorElNav["menu"]}
  onClose={toggleDropdown("menu", false)}
  sx={{
    zIndex: 1000,
    width: 150,
    [`& .MuiDrawer-paper`]: {
      pt: 9,
      width: 150,
    },
  }}
>
  <NavbarMenuDropdown
    toggleDropdown={toggleDropdown}
    navbarPages={navbarPages}
  />
</Drawer>
```

The outcome could be further styled to match the desired result, perhaps consider to reference this [example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#clipped-under-the-app-bar) by MUI, although it is for a permanent drawer.

**Original**

Perhaps try add `zIndex` to the `Drawer`, a basic option would be using the `sx` prop:

More about the `sx` prop in MUI: [document](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/)

```
<Drawer
  //  Maybe this should be "left" as shown in the picture?
  anchor="top"
  open={anchorElNav["menu"]}
  onClose={toggleDropdown("menu", false)}
  //  Add this because app bar has z-index of 1100, drawer 1200 by default
  sx={{ zIndex: 1000 }}
>
  <NavbarMenuDropdown
    toggleDropdown={toggleDropdown}
    navbarPages={navbarPages}
  />
</Drawer>
```

Comment: When I add the zIndex, the Drawer object ends up behind the AppBar, not below. Would you have another solution? Appreciate your help!

Comment: @chu-js Thanks for clarifying, I updated the answer with a possible approach.  Not sure if this will achieve the desired result, but also added some references from MUI and hopefully it would help.